# Button inside relative layout with background is too small

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Typical search layout having RelativeLayout, TextView, EditText and Button

I have `a.9.png` image having height of 46px

The relative layout looks ok, but the views inside of it is too small, the Button don't adapt  the height size and EditText too.(using hdpi in tablet)

This is my code::

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cuadrobusqueda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_buscar_servicios"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:text="Button" android:textSize="11sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: `make button's height and width wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the image you supplied in android:background="@drawable/bg_buscar_servicios", It's height and also don't give height of RealtiveLayout if you want to make it small and need more screen area just below it then try to give android:layout_weight which will automatically adjust according to your device.

But i'm sure problem with your Image check it out first..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `32dp` for button's height which is like `48px` on hdpi devices. Try using `wrap_content` and it will automatically resize your button.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your 9 patch has a large enough content area.
If you need help with that please post the 9 patch on the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cuadrobusqueda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView" />
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:text="Button" android:textSize="11sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```